# Update Value of Table from Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with no pk, and I need to update an import of a specific record with the sum of others import from the same table with some conditions.

try to explain a little bit better.

I have Table X, with columns ID and IMP (that's the import I need to update). So I'm trying to update value of IMP of record with ID=5 with the sum of the others IMPORT where records id are < 5.

```
UPDATE X old
SET old.IMP = 
  (SELECT SUM(new.IMP)
  FROM X new
  WHERE new.ID<5)
WHERE old.ID = 5;
```

but it takes ages to update. I don't even know if it finishes, because it took too much and I alwasy aborted the script.

Am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT**

Yeah. You asked me the proper situation. Working on a table really small, with about 2000 records. No indexes of course. I still have no idea why it takes so much. If I just run the script to get the SUM, it takes some ms, but with update it seems is going to stuck in something I don't understand.

**EDIT 2**

First rule of computers: Reboot. And that's how everything come back to work again. No idea what happend, but just reboot the machine and now the script works correctly. Sorry for any troubles.

Comment: How large is the table? How many rows, what indexes, and what's the explain plan. I suspect that your table is not really called X, and you are possibly simplifying the situation.

Comment: How much data are you trying to process ? Even with proper indexes (which you said you don't have), updating a large chunck of data in one go can be stressful for the undo segment as well as the alert logs.  Can you maybe prepare a secondary table with the SUM values for each ID that will be updated.  And then in a loop update it in smaller batches.  Updating a large amount of data could also result in an escalation to a  table lock, which means you may be wating on that and not even doing anything.

Comment: Edited with situation I'm working on

Answer (score 0):

Run these queries and share the output:

```
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 from dba_segments where segment_name = 'X';

select owner, index_name, column_name from dba_ind_columns where table_name = 'X';

select count(1) from X;
```

If you have access to OEM, you can monitor the sql statement to see if there is progress or blockers on the query.